# How do I insert a NULL value into a db table in java?

Tags: java, sql

The problem is that I can't figure out how to insert a null value. The column is date and if it's empty it just adds the current date to the db by default, but I don't know how to leave it empty or null if the user doesn't specify a custom date.

`statement.executeUpdate("insert into table values(null, 100, 'text')");`

This is the query. I've tried to skip the first value, insert a null, insert empty string, a 0 value. nothing seems to do the trick.

Comment: insert into table (colum2,colum3) values(100, 'text') leave the column which you want to set null.

Comment: @keyser yeah you are correct , I also posted another Solution as answer.

Comment: may be you have provided default value for the column. In that case it can't be `null`. Check DDL of the table again.

Comment: @user3218114 yes, I set the default value to CURRENT_DATE. But if it can't be null, how do I use the default value then? I mean what's the purpose of a default value if you have to insert something anyway? Maybe I should just set the column type to text and create the default date string in java..I'll probably need some kind of a date parser for retreaving the dates anyway

Comment: the default value means set it when it's value is `null` otherwise set the provided one. remove the `default` value check if you want to allow `null` values as well.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'd want to do here. To use the default value when I insert null or empty or whatev. But I how can I insert a null or empty? I can't. That's the whole problem here. I can insert an empty value from sqlite manager and then it uses the default value like it should. But how to do that in java is the big question(?)

Comment: OP: You mentioned the advantage of a default value itself: it inserts the current date by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this form, where you specify what columns you intend to set:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...) 
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

In your case:

```
insert into table (col2, col3) values (100, 'text')
```

(where of course col2 and col3 is the column names of your table)

Edit:
The date column (col1) will probably need the constraint "Default null" for this to work as you intended.

Comment: yess, now I got it! Just leave the column I want null out and fill the other values in. This seems to work! This is a good way. I was filling just values so could not leave any column empty but this way you can.

Comment: Doesn't this set the date to its default value?

Comment: @keyser Good catch, the column should have the constraint "Default null" for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO temp(val) VALUES (?)";
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
if (/* int value is not null */) {
   st.setInt(1, value);
} else {
   set.setNull(1, Types.INTEGER);
}
count  = st.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I really don't understand this. Seems a bit complicated too. I just want to insert a null value, not check anything

Answer (score 0):

in your column_date uncheck NOT NULL then you can insert NULL VALUES

simple code "INSERT INTO `table_name` (`field_name`) VALUES (NULL)

Comment: yes I have it unchecked and the code you wrote would probably work in straight sql but in java just using 'NULL' takes it as a string so it won't work for some reason. Null is also a reserved java command and won't work without double quotes either. I'm stuck

Comment: its because you using ResultSet, java will save as String 'null' to your column table. You need prepared statement,when your variable String is null, prepared statement will insert as NULL values not String 'null'